# How to make dynamic chain of middleware in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently working on a project to develop an API manager to control an existing API.

It contains a list of "before" and "after" middlewares, which are used to do things like security checking and logging. And a "service" middleware to do http request to the existing API. But the problem is that I want to make the order the middleware being executed to be dynamic, meaning that I could load some configuration file to change the order the middleaware get executed every time the request comes in.

here is my previous code:

```
'use strict';
// Loading the express library
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var service = require('./routes/index');


// Testing configurable middleware
var confirguration = {
    before1: {
        priority: 100,
        enable: true
    },
    before2: {
        priority: 80,
        enable: true
    },
    service: {
        priority: 50,
        enable: true
    },
    after1: {
        priority: 30,
        enable: true
    },
    after2: {
        priority: 10,
        enable: true
    }
}

var before1 = require('./example_middleware/before1');
var before2 = require('./example_middleware/before2');
var after1 = require('./example_middleware/after1');
var after2 = require('./example_middleware/after2');
// Fake request to simulate the /service
var fakeRequest = require('./example_middleware/fake_request');

// Function to sort the order of the middleware to be executed
var sortConfig = function(confirguration){
    var sortable = [];
    for (var middleware in confirguration)
        // To make middlewares configurable
        if (confirguration[middleware]['enable'] == true){
            sortable.push([middleware, confirguration[middleware]['priority']]);
        }

    sortable.sort(function(a, b) {return b[1] - a[1]});
    return sortable;
}

// var sortedConfig = [];
var middlewareSet = new Array();
app.use('/test', function(request, response, next){
    var middleware;
    var sortedConfig = sortConfig(confirguration);

    for (var i in sortedConfig){
        switch(sortedConfig[i][0]){
            case 'before1':
                middleware = before1;
                break;
            case 'before2':
                middleware = before2;
                break;
            case 'service':
                middleware = fakeRequest;
                break;
            case 'after1':
                middleware = after1;
                break;
            case 'after2':
                middleware = after2;
                break;
        }


        // console.log(sortedConfig[i][0]);
        // Execute the middleware in expected order
        middlewareSet.push(middleware);
    }
    // request.sortedConfig = sortedConfig;
    console.log(middlewareSet);
    console.log('middleware list sorted');
    next();
});

app.use('/test', middlewareSet);
```

But I keep getting the same error message coming from the app.use() at the last line:

> app.use() requires middleware functions

It works if I use:

```
app.use('/test', [before1, before2, fakeRequest, after1, after2]);
```

But it's not dynamic though, what did I misunderstand? There must be a way to do this in express.js.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I modified my code according to Ryan's answer, here is the code:

```
var async = require('async');
app.use('/test', configurableMiddleWare);

function configurableMiddleWare(req, res, next) {

    var operations = [];

    var middleware;

    var sortedConfig = sortConfig(confirguration);

   // push each middleware you want to run
    sortedConfig.forEach(function(fn) {

        switch(fn[0]){
            case 'before1':
                middleware = before1;
                break;
            case 'before2':
                middleware = before2;
                break;
            case 'service':
                middleware = fakeRequest;
                break;
            case 'after1':
                middleware = after1;
                break;
            case 'after2':
                middleware = after2;
                break;
        }

        operations.push(middleware); // could use fn.bind(null, req, res) to pass in vars  
    });

    console.log('middleware list sorted');
   // now actually invoke the middleware in series
    async.series(operations, function(err) {
        if(err) {
        // one of the functions passed back an error so handle it here
            return next(err);
        }
      // no errors so pass control back to express
        next();
    });

}
```

Just to make sure I haven't made any mistakes in my test middleware, here is an example of one of them:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/')
    .all(function(request, response, next){
        console.log('This is middleware BEFORE1');
        next();
    });


module.exports = router;
```

Now, when I run my application, I got the following error from npm:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
>
> > at Function.proto.handle (/Users/jialunliu/Documents/SOA_project/FAT-LADY/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:130:28)
> >        at router (/Users/jialunliu/Documents/SOA_project/FAT-LADY/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:35:12)
> >        at /Users/jialunliu/Documents/SOA_project/FAT-LADY/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:610:21
> >        at /Users/jialunliu/Documents/SOA_project/FAT-LADY/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:249:17
> >        at iterate (/Users/jialunliu/Documents/SOA_project/FAT-LADY/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:149:13)
> >        at async.eachSeries (/Users/jialunliu/Documents/SOA_project/FAT-LADY/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:165:9)
> >        at _asyncMap (/Users/jialunliu/Documents/SOA_project/FAT-LADY/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:248:13)
> >        at Object.mapSeries (/Users/jialunliu/Documents/SOA_project/FAT-LADY/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:231:23)
> >        at Object.async.series (/Users/jialunliu/Documents/SOA_project/FAT-LADY/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:608:19)
> >        at configurableMiddleWare (/Users/jialunliu/Documents/SOA_project/FAT-LADY/app.js:135:11)

Which is coming from the line
`async.series(operations, function(err){})`

I am keep getting this kind of error message, saying the function could not read from this array of functions "operations"....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, you will just need to tweak a few things. I would register one top level function with `app.use()` and then do all of your dynamic stuff within that function. Updating my answer to a working example. Be sure to install async first `npm install --save async`

```
// define all middleware functions
var middleware = {
    mw1: function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('mw 1');
        next();
    },
    mw2: function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('mw 2');
        next();
    },
    mw3: function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('mw 3');
        next();
    },
    mw4: function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('mw 4');
        next();
    }

};

// register our "top level function"
app.use(configurableMiddleware);
var requestCount = 1; // this is just for the working example

function configurableMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    var isEvenRequest = requestCount++ % 2 === 0; // simple logic to alternate which "configurable" middleware to use

    var operations; // in the real world you could build this array dynamically, for now we just hardcode two scenarios as an example

    // Each request to http://localhost:3000 will alternate which middleware is used, so you will see a different log each time
    if(isEvenRequest) {
        console.log('Even request should log mw2 and mw4');
        // .bind(null, req, res) makes sure that the middleware gets the request and response objects when they are invoked, 
        // as of this point they still haven't been invoked...
        operations = [middleware.mw2.bind(null, req, res), middleware.mw4.bind(null, req, res)];
    }
    else {
        console.log('Odd request should log mw1 and mw3');
        operations = [middleware.mw1.bind(null, req, res), middleware.mw3.bind(null, req, res)];
    }

    // invoke each middleware in series - you could also do async.parallel if the order of middleware doesn't matter
    // using the async module: https://github.com/caolan/async
    async.series(operations, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('There was a problem running the middleware!');
            return next(err);
        }
        // all middleware has been run
        next();
    });
}
```

For more info on .bind() see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Thank you for your response, but why don't you just pass the "sortedMiddleware" into the async.series() function?

Comment: And how do I pass the sorted array of middlewares into your function? Can I just use a global variable?

Comment: How am I supposed to issue an error from one of the middleware and handle it properly? I tried to use `next(err)`, but it doesn't seem like the error is handled properly.

Comment: Nice solution. It is however not possible to modify `req` and `res` in these middlewares, am I right? Because they get bound before anything is executed… so if I write something to `req` in the first executed middleware, it will be lost in the second one. Any solution for that?

Comment: @deyhle When you use .bind(null, req, res) it is passing a reference to the `req` and `res` objects - so if you make a change to the `req` in the first middleware you will be able to see that change in the last middleware since they are all seeing the same `req` object.

Answer (score 6):

## `connect-sequence`: a dedicated node module for that specific purpose:

You can just use the module `connect-sequence` which is designed for that purpose:

```
npm install --save connect-sequence
```

> see:
>
> - the npmjs page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-sequence
> - or the github project: https://github.com/sirap-group/connect-sequence

and then, here an example of usage:

```
/**
 * Product API
 * @module
 */

var ConnectSequence = require('connect-sequence')
var productsController = require('./products.controller')

module.exports = productRouter

function productRouter (app) {
  app.route('/api/products/:productId')
  .get(function (req, res, next) {
    // Create a ConnectSequence instance and setup it with the current `req`,
    // `res` objects and the `next` callback
    var seq = new ConnectSequence(req, res, next)

    // build the desired middlewares sequence thanks to:
    // - ConnectSequence#append(mid0, ..., mid1),
    // - ConnectSequence#appendList([mid0, ..., mid1])
    // - and ConnectSequence#appendIf(condition, mid)

    if (req.query.filter) {
      seq.append(productsController.filter)
    }

    if (req.query.format) {
      seq.append(
        productsController.validateFormat,
        productsController.beforeFormat,
        productsController.format,
        productsController.afterFormat
      )
    }

    // append the productsController.prepareResponse middleware to the sequence
    // only if the condition `req.query.format && req.formatedProduct` is true
    // at the moment where the middleware would be called.
    // So the condition is tested after the previous middleware is called and thus
    // if the previous modifies the `req` object, we can test it.
    seq.appendIf(isProductFormatted, productsController.prepareResponse)

    seq.append(productsController.sendResponse)

    // run the sequence
    seq.run()
  })

  app.param('productId', function (req, res, next, id) {
    // ... yield the product by ID and bind it to the req object
  })

  function isProductFormatted (req) {
    return Boolean(req.formatedProduct)
  }
}
```

## This is open source, PR are welcome!

If you like and use connect-sequence, but if you find bug or need some new features, feel free to post issues or submit pull requests!

Comment: it is bugous, I've tried Multer, Auth0, none works in every order

Answer (score 2):

Based on the idea behind @Ryan's code I came up with this function. It executes a list of middleware in order binding the variables as needed, allowing everything to be executed by just `executeMiddlewareList([middleware1, middleware2...], req, res, next);`. For each middleware`req, res` is passed and the callback from `async.eachSeries`. This means when `next()` is called inside the middleware, then next one will be handled from the list. If middleware throws an error with `next(err)`, execution will stop and you can manually handle this.

```js
function executeMiddlewareList (middlewareList, req, res, next) {
   async.eachSeries(middlewareList, function(middleware,callback) {
      middleware.bind(null,req,res,callback)()
   }, function(err) {
      if (err) return res.status(500).json({error: err});
      next();
   })
}

function testMid (number) {
   return function (req, res, next) {
      log.debug('req.test from', req.test, " to ", number);
      req.test=number;
      next();
   }
}

router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
   m.executeMiddlewareList([test(1), test(2)], req, res, next);
   //Output: req.test from undefined to 1
   //        req.test from 1 to 2
}, function (req,res) {
    //Do stuff after the executeMiddlewareList, req.test = 2
})
```

Comment: Thanks !, your solution works while Ryan's doesn't for async middlewares

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find the answer according the Ryan's, the code would look like this:

```
function configurableMiddleWare(req, res, next) {

    var operations = [];

    var middleware;

    var sortedConfig = sortConfig(confirguration);

   // push each middleware you want to run
    sortedConfig.forEach(function(fn) {

        switch(fn[0]){
            case 'before1':
                middleware = before1;
                break;
            case 'before2':
                middleware = before2;
                break;
            case 'service':
                middleware = fakeRequest;
                break;
            case 'after1':
                middleware = after1;
                break;
            case 'after2':
                middleware = after2;
                break;
        }

        console.log(fn[0]);
        console.log(middleware);

        operations.push(middleware.bind(null, req, res)); // could use fn.bind(null, req, res) to pass in vars  
    });

    console.log('middleware list sorted');
   // now actually invoke the middleware in series
    async.series(operations, function(err) {
        if(err) {
        // one of the functions passed back an error so handle it here
            return next(err);
        }
        console.log('middleware get executed');
        // no errors so pass control back to express
        next();
    });

}

app.use('/test', configurableMiddleWare);
```

The key step is indeed the `operations.push(middleware.bind(null, req, res));`
Which to be honest, I don't understand what does it mean exactly. I know this is passing "req" and "res" variable into the middleware, but I don't get what the point of the "null" in the front. Much appreciated if someone could help me clarify this.

Comment: The first argument is the context. Similar to how you would use call or apply to change the context of 'this'.