# Can a middleware return middlewares in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to combine different middlewares (multer and auth0 here) together to lower code complexity. Can I write one middleware that returns either middlewares or just `next()` (if the environment/parameters don't require its execution).

Something like this:

```
const constraints = {
    'local': {
        'GET': {},
        'POST': {
            'skills': {
                secured: true,
                upload: true,
                geolocation: false,
                illustrations: true,
                schema: skillsSchema
            },
            'donations': {
                secured: true,
                upload: true,
                geolocation: true,
                illustrations: false,
                schema: donationsSchema
            }
        }
    },
}
```

---

**Should I return next ? or next() ? or true**

```
function middleware(req, res, next) {
    const section = req.params[0]
    const method = req.method
    const { body } = req
    const {
        secured,
        upload,
        geolocation,
        illustrations,
        schema
    } = constraints[process.env.NODE_ENV][method][section];
    // Should I return next ? or next() ? or true
    const uploading = !upload ? next() : ops.multer
    const securing = !secured ? next() : ops.auth0
    const geoValid = !geolocation ? true : new PipeLine({
        point: {
            lat: body.lat,
            lng: body.lng
        }
    })
    .isPointInsidePolygon(coordinates)
    const undrawValid = !illustrations ? true : new PipeLine({
        body: body
    }).undrawSplit().joiValidate(schema).undrawJoin()
    res.locals.magicPipeLine = { geoValid, undrawValid }
    return [uploading, securing]
}
```

The route would be:

```
router.post(/^\/(donations|skills|blogs)/,
  middleware,
  async (req, res, next) => {
```

Comment: I have the same problem. The first middleware configure the next ones.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return middleware from middleware, but you can return an array of middleware and use the spread operator.

```js
const items = [middleware1, middleware2, (req, res, next)=>{ next() }]

app.get('/foo', ...items)
```

You also can call middleware from middleware.

1. You should not call `next()` if your encapsulated middleware calls it.  You should invoke the middleware manually if you want to integrate it in yours, and send it the `next` value (not call it).  Here is an example:  [Calling a middleware from within a middleware in NodeJS/ExpressJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572752/calling-a-middleware-from-within-a-middleware-in-nodejs-expressjs)
2. Returning values from middleware will not affect the flow at all.

Comment: calling a middleware from within a middleware ? this is not what I want, here I simply want to write a "Function" that returns an array of middlewares (as Express expects). This function itself, I cannot call outside the route definition, as it needs `req` and `res` itself, so it is by definition a middleware as well.

Comment: This function, must always return an array of middlewares (configured somehow, to be either just next, or other job they are supposed to do)

Comment: it is like construction middlewares on runtime, first middleware is my function that return the future middlewares (configured)./

Comment: Then the answer is NO. I will update response.

Comment: You are right about calling a middleware from within another, my problem gets down to this I didn't have the logic. I found what seems a solution to construct multiple successive or async calls https://stackoverflow.com/a/29090673/1951298

Comment: I think building an array and spreading it is the cleanest option.

Answer (score 0):

The middleware state logic in Express.js is about working on request and response parameters in a sequential way.

You should be doing stuff with the request parameters (params, query, body etc.) and then assigning it to a namespace can be used in next() function.

My bare-minimal authorization flow is something like this.

```
const authenticate = (roles) => (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { usr, rol, exp } = decode(req.headers.authorization, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    if (exp > new Date().getTime()) {
      if (roles === 'all' || roles.includes(rol)) {
        req.user = usr;
        next();
      } else res.status(401).send('Wrong user type.');
    } else res.status(401).send('Expired token');
  } catch (e) { res.status(401).send('You need a token.'); }
};
```

As you'll see I'm payloading body with the "processed" authentication header.

You should return next() in your middlewares.

Comment: I know, but call it "Pipeline()" instead of "middleware()", technically, can I return `[multer, auth0]` which are middlewares ?

Comment: The only implementation i made with multer is using it with passport in a simple REST API.

```router.post('/', auth('all'), uploader.single('file'), upload.create.single);```

As in the example, as far as i know, you can add infinite amount of middlewares to a route, why would you need [multer, auth0] i really dont know.